# Unable to build to Mac using Xamarin on Windows Vs2015

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Has anybody managed to resolve the error below?

I am no longer able to connect to the mac from my windows 7 visual studio 2015. The logs are as follows:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The file
>   '/Users/applex/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyApp.App.iOS/deef5454584ee33b5/obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/build-signature/signature'
>   was not found on the Mac

Has anyone managed to get past this error?

Comment: have you got the correct provisioning profiles installed on to your Mac?

Comment: Is your Xamarin.iOS in visual studio updated? Specifically to the same version of the Xamarin.iOS in the Mac